# Clear or disable aliases in zsh

Tags: shell, zsh, alias, oh-my-zsh

I installed oh-my-zsh to make terminal use a bit easier. One thing that bugs me though is the prolific aliases added by it, like "ga", "gap", "gcmsg", "_", which are harder to remember than the original command, and pollutes the command hash table.

So is there a way to disable aliases altogether? Or a way to clear all aliases so that I can put it in my `.zshrc`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't want any of oh-my-zsh's aliases, but you want to keep other aliases, you can save the aliases before loading oh-my-zsh

```
save_aliases=$(alias -L)
```

and restore them afterwards.

```
eval $save_aliases; unset save_aliases
```

If you want to remove all aliases at some point, you can use `unalias -m '*'` (remove all aliases matching `*`, i.e. all of them).

If you absolutely hate aliases and don't want to ever see one, you can make the `alias` builtin inoperative: `unalias -m '*'; alias () { : }`. Or you can simply turn off alias expansion with `setopt no_aliases`.

Comment: Thanks! I like this solution because it will still work after updates to oh-my-zsh and its git plugin.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `unalias` with `-m` option:

```
unalias -m '*'
```

to delete all defined aliases

Comment: When I append this line to `.zshrc`, there is still one alias `globurl='noglob urlglobber '` left. Any idea why?

Comment: Maybe it's loaded after `unalias` ran. ,Maybe you should put the `unalias` command at the end of your `.zshrc`

Comment: I did put it at the end. That is why it is so confusing.

Comment: What is output of `zstyle`?

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/netheril96/70be43f8627eea5603f1 for the `zstyle` output.

Comment: I recursively grepped .oh-my-zsh directory and cannot find any thing containing the word `globber` or `globurl`.

Comment: @SiyuanRen: I think because of these lines `url-globbers
(eval)  :url-quote-magic 'zmodload -i zsh/parameter;
  reply=( noglob
   ${(k)galiases[(R)(* |)(noglob|urlglobber|globurl) *]:-}
   ${(k)aliases[(R)(* |)(noglob|urlglobber|globurl) *]:-} )'`. It returns new alias definition.

Comment: It is just odd that this is defined but nowhere to be found in my filesystem.

Comment: @SiyuanRen: You can post it as another question, to get more details answer from another users. I don't have deep knowledge about `zsh` to give you an explanation about that.

Comment: @SiyuanRen This alias is defined when the function `url-quote-magic` is loaded (see `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Zle/url-quote-magic` or wherever it is on your system). Oh-my-zsh binds `self-insert` to `url-quote-magic`.

Answer (score 9):

If you only want to remove the git aliases, I recommend one of the following two choices:

1. Change `~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh` by removing all the aliases at the bottom
2. Make a copy of that plugin (recommended location: `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/git-noalias/git-noalias.plugin.zsh`), edit that copy to not have the aliases, and then change your `~/.zshrc` to do `plugins=(git-noalias)` instead of `plugins=(git)`.

This will give you all the benefits of the plugin (I'm not sure what they are but they may be related to the automatic Git status/branch information displayed within Git folders) without the aliases.

Comment: The advantage of not having aliases but keep the [git plugin](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh) of oh-my-zsh is the functions.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to [skip loading aliases in ohmyzsh](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh#skip-aliases) via `zstyle` settings.

The "alias skip" filtering is quite granular, after changes merged in April 2023 ([issue](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/10644), [pull request](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/pull/11550)). It is possible to, for example, skip all aliases, or only [`git` aliases](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/git#aliases).

> ### [Skip aliases](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh#skip-aliases)
>
> If you want to skip default Oh My Zsh aliases (those defined in `lib/*` files) or plugin aliases,
> you can use the settings below in your `~/.zshrc` file, **before Oh My Zsh is loaded**. Note that
> there are many different ways to skip aliases, depending on your needs.
>
> ```bash
> # Skip all aliases, in lib files and enabled plugins
> zstyle ':omz:*' aliases no
>
> # ...other filtering variants...
>
> # Skip only the aliases from the git plugin
> zstyle ':omz:plugins:git' aliases no
> ```

---

Other suggestions:

- Use [`alias` to list current aliases](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Cheatsheet#commands).
- Enable the [`aliases` plugin](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/aliases) and use `als` to list aliases by group.
- Enable the [`alias-finder` plugin](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/alias-finder) to learn (of) aliases matching your own commands.
- Enable the [`globalias` plugin](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/globalias) to expand, among other things, aliases typed at the terminal.

Answer (score -1):

**Simple method:**
If the problem is the multiple lines of git aliases comment out the aliases you want to *disable*

```
nano ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh
```

comment out the unwanted lines *#*, to go faster using nano make use of the **Replace** function

```
alias g='git'
#alias ga='git add'
#alias gaa='git add --all'
...
```